# Stripe Connect refund with transfer reversal: insufficient funds

Tags: java, stripe-payments

We are currently using Stripe Connect to accept payments on behalf of externals platforms. The payment process works fine (we are using Transfers to transfer fund directly on payment to the connected account), like this:

```
PaymentIntentCreateParams.Builder paramsBuilder = PaymentIntentCreateParams
    .builder()
    .setAmount(getFinalPurchasePrice())
    .setCustomer(customerStripeId)
    .setPaymentMethod(getStripePaymentMethodId())
    .setConfirm(true)
    .setOffSession(true)
    .setOnBehalfOf(stripeConnectedAccountId)
    .setTransferData(PaymentIntentCreateParams.TransferData.builder()
            .setAmount(getFinalTransferPrice())
            .setDestination(stripeConnectedAccountId)
            .build())
    .setCurrency(getCurrency().toString().toLowerCase());
```

Now we are facing the issue of refunds. In test mode they worked fine (and as expected). But in live mode we are getting "insufficient funds". This is our request:

```
RefundCreateParams refundCreateParams = RefundCreateParams.builder()
        .setReverseTransfer(true)
        .setCharge(charge.getId())
        .setAmount(amount)
        .setReason(RefundCreateParams.Reason.REQUESTED_BY_CUSTOMER)
        .build();

Refund.create(refundCreateParams, requestOptions);
```

And this is the response:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "Insufficient funds in your Stripe balance to refund this amount.",
    "request_log_url": "xxxx",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

The charge used was a successful charge and was for more than the amount specified here. The connected account's balance also is high enough to cover the refund.

Our account currently does not have enough balance to cover the amount specified in the refund, but since we are using transfer reversal i would have assumed that the reversed transfer is reponsible to cover this. Am i wrong here, or are we doing anything wrong?

Comment: I had a quite same issue few months ago. The fact is that you want to refund an amount but you have been tax charged by Stripe (1.4% + .25ct). If it's your first payment, you may not be able to API refund I think. This is why it worked in test mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after chatting with Stripe support. As i said we use Stripe Connect with transfers to immediatly transfer a certain amount to the connected account and keep a part for ourselves.

If we start a refund with transfer reversal it takes this "cut" into account and calculates what it needs to take from the connected account and what part it takes from the platform account. This lead the "insufficient funds" error, since our platform account did not have enough funds to cover that part at this time.